# Can multiple documents be updated by multiple documents in mongo or mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, insert-update

I have a variable which is an array of documents. I want to update these documents in mongo. I'm using mongoose for ORM.

For example I have these objects in mongo:

```
[{name: 'John', age: 10}, {name: 'Mary', age: 12}]
```

and I want to update them with:

```
[{name: 'John', age: 11}, {name: 'Mary', age: 13}]
```

where `name` is the key, so it's a many-to-many function.

Can this be done in single query?

Comment: Looks like $set-ing the whole array should work just fine.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you please point me to such an example?